# ReRender everything except target within <Apex:Repeat>?

Tags: apex, visualforce, html

I'm currently building a web app to support our sales team and I'm running into a design/functionality issue.

When the visualforce page is brought up it gives a list of products or services we offer, and a button next to them to click to select it.

Some items are not able to show up unless a certain item is selected.

This is relatively easy but the issue comes up that below certain other products there are expandable options below them, and rerendering the section causes the expandable options to close.

This is visually jarring and doesn't function smoothly.

So now I need to find a way to rerender just the changes, or rerender a section without rerendering certain objects.

Example:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="Products Section">
<ul>
<apex:repeat>
<apex:outputPanel rendered="Does required object need to be selected? If so, is it?">
<li>
Product Name, and select button
</li>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:repeat>
</ul>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't really do that. It just doesn't work out well. Without going full client-side scripting, what you can do is simply back-up and restore the configuration of the toggled items. To do this, you need two parts: the script that stores the configuration, and the script that reapplies it.

For the first part, just store the data as part of your expanding/collapsing function:

```
var expanded = {};
function collapseOrExpand(e) {
    e.target.classList.toggle('expanded');
    expanded[e.target.id] = e.target.classList.contains('expanded')];
}
```

Then, after a reRender, just set the values back:

```
function restoreExpandedState() {
    var el = document.querySelectorAll('.productRow');
    [].forEach.call(el, function(v) {
        if(expanded[v.id]) {
            v.classList.add('expanded');
        }
    });
}
```

The final piece is to simply call `restoreExpandedState` when your re-render completes:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="..." action="{!...}" reRender="..." oncomplete="restoreExpandedState()">
```

You can use oncomplete for any element that supports reRender, including commandButton, commandLink, actionFunction, actionSupport, and actionPoller.